# How to select a specific number of rows and convert them into named columns

Tags: sql, pivot, sql-server-2019

I am hanging on this problem for hours.

A very simple query:

```
SELECT 
 RoomId,
 WaterMeterNumber
FROM Watermeter
WHERE RoomId = GR.RoomId
```

SQL Result:

| RoomId | WaterMeterNumber |
| --- | --- |
| 95E5ACE0-FEE4-4D33-BC22-0DCF7B1155CF | SZ12800491 |
| 95E5ACE0-FEE4-4D33-BC22-0DCF7B1155CF | 3375791 |
| 95E5ACE0-FEE4-4D33-BC22-0DCF7B1155CF | 45332 |
| 95E5ACE0-FEE4-4D33-BC22-0DCF7B1155CF | SK9649 |

And I want the query result to be like that:

| RoomId | Number1 | Number2 | Number3 | Number4 | Number5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 95E5ACE0-FEE4-4D33-BC22-0DCF7B1155CF | SZ12800491 | 3375791 | 45332 | SK9649 |  |

I always want to show the numbers of the first five watermeters of a room.
So the columns need to have a static name.

I already tried combining five windowing functions in mssql but the problem is that I can not dynamically set the room ID inside the window query.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY WaterMeterId ASC) AS rownumber,
    RoomId,
    WaterMeterNumber
  FROM WaterMeter
   WHERE RoomId='95E5ACE0-FEE4-4D33-BC22-0DCF7B1155CF'
                
) AS X
WHERE rownumber = 1
```

This query would work but how I said the RoomId needs to be dynamic.

I want it that way, so I can use it in another main query.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY WaterMeterId ASC) AS rownumber,
    RoomId,
    WaterMeterNumber
  FROM X.WaterMeter
   WHERE X.RoomId= GR.RoomId
                
) AS X
WHERE rownumber = 1
```

Is there a way to achieve this with a pivot function or smth like that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT RoomId,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN WaterMeterNumber END) as watermeter_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN WaterMeterNumber END) as watermeter_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 3 THEN WaterMeterNumber END) as watermeter_3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 4 THEN WaterMeterNumber END) as watermeter_4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 5 THEN WaterMeterNumber END) as watermeter_5
FROM (SELECT wm.*
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RoomId ORDER BY WaterMeterId ASC) AS seqnum,
      FROM WaterMeter wem
     ) wm
GROUP BY RoomId;
```

If you want this for only one `RoomId`, then add:

```
WHERE RoomId='95E5ACE0-FEE4-4D33-BC22-0DCF7B1155CF'
```

to the subquery.

Comment: Oh wow... that works just perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot in sql. if you want to show rows to columns.

For your reference I have created 2 tables 1st is tbltest and 2nd is tbltest2

In tblTest below are the data.

[image]

and in the tblTest2 below are the data.

[image]

you can use pivot for converting rows to columns just like below query.

Select roomId,[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfLhl.png) AS Number1, [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6YxK.png) AS Number2, [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clpfo.png) AS Number3, [4] AS Number4, [5] AS Number5  from
(
Select  t.roomId,WaterMeterNumber,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by T.roomId  order by T.roomId) as Sno from tblTest T
inner Join tblTest2 T2 on T2.roomId=T.roomId) as P
Pivot
( min(waterMeterNumber) for sno in ([3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clpfo.png),[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clpfo.png),[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clpfo.png),[4],[5])) as pvt

and result is like that:

[image]